# Use of <object> from javascript to Qt c++ ( example in this post )

Tags: javascript, qt

i'm reading a book about Qt, there is an example that i don't understand, where we use an html page : i don't understand how all the `<object>` from the html page are "analyzed" by the c++ : i was looking at the BrowserWindow class, where the logic seems to happen : `new BrowserWindow(url, new WebPage);` but i did not find anything there...

Here's the code : first we have an html page with several `<object>` :

```
<object type="application/x-qt-plugin" classid="QLineEdit"
    id="nameEdit" height="30">Can't load QLineEdit plugin!</object>
<p>
<object type="application/x-qt-plugin" classid="MatrixWidget"
    id="leftMatrix" width="124" height="94" readonly="1">
Can't load MatrixWidget plugin!</object>
```

Then we have a WebPage class that is supposed to analyse the html : `createPlugin` responds to the type "application/x-qt-plugin" :

```
QObject* WebPage::createPlugin(const QString &classId,
        const QUrl&, const QStringList &parameterNames,
        const QStringList &parameterValues)
{
    QWidget *widget = 0;
    if (classId == "MatrixWidget") {
        widget = new MatrixWidget(view());
        int index = parameterNames.indexOf("readonly");
        if (index > -1)
            static_cast<MatrixWidget*>(widget)->setReadOnly(
                   static_cast<bool>(parameterValues[index].toInt()));
    }
    else { ...
```

And the `main.cpp` is :

```
QString url = QUrl::fromLocalFile(AQP::applicationPathOf() +
                                      "/matrixquiz.html").toString();
    BrowserWindow *browser = new BrowserWindow(url, new WebPage);
```

And the browserWindow class constructor is :

```
BrowserWindow::BrowserWindow(const QString &url, QWebPage *webPage,
                             QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags flags)
    : QFrame(parent, flags)
{
    setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box|QFrame::Raised);

    webView = new QWebView;
    if (webPage)
        webView->setPage(webPage);
    load(url);

    createActions();
    createToolBar();
    createLayout();
    createConnections();
}
```

So, my question is : how do we check all the `<object>` in the html file?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When QtWebKit is parsing the webpage, if it finds an `<object>` tag with a `type="application/x-qt-plugin"` attribute, it will call the `QWebPage::createPlugin` function to try to create the plugin.

You don't have to explicitly check the object tags, QtWebKit does this all for you and converts it into the `createPlugin` call.

Comment: alright thanks, so does the thing happen when we set the page : `webView->setPage(webPage)` ? Thanks

Comment: It is when the page is loaded by `QWebPage`. You can use a `QWebPage` without a web view. A page load can be triggered by `QWebFrame::load`, `QWebView::load` or other functions such as `setContent`.